# Angular 2 routing issue child and parent

Tags: angular

I have found many routing issues here on Stack Overflow, but not an answer to my question. After user logs in, user gets routed to a parent that has child route:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
},
{
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
        {
            // without this routing does not work
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'parent'
        },
        { 
            path: 'child', 
            component: ChildComponent,
        },
    ]
},
//... more routes
```

My problem is that without the following mentioned in `children`:

```
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'parent'
```

User doesn't get routed to parent route at all from login page. But this also messes with my url and instead of just

`localhost:3000/parent` I get `localhost:3000/parent/parent`. That still displays the correct component. But when user navigates elsewhere, there is error:

> Cannot match any routes: 'something/something'

How can I fix this, thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your url is probably caused when you navigate to your parent-component, and if the path is `''`, meaning `localhost:3000/parent` in your case,

then you `redirectTo` `parent` again, therefore causes `localhost:3000/parent/parent`

Try just to remove the `redirectTo: 'parent'` and see what happens!

Comment: But I wrote route does not route if I leave it away.

Comment: Did you leave the `path: ''` in the children, and just remove `redirectTo: 'parent'`?

Comment: als you could instead, redirect to `child`